# 'Do/Don't' in 3rd person singular

Tags: verbs, agreement

A lot of song lyrics include phrases where "do/don't" is used instead of "does/doesn't" with subjects in 3rd person singular.

We are taught that is incorrect grammar. But, given how widespread that practice is, is it really incorrect? Or is it just informal?

How do you feel about it if you're a native American or British speaker and you encounter such a phrase, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Whether or not "do/don't" is available in the third person singular is a matter of dialect. For speakers of some dialects, it does indeed exist as a natural variant that you would expect to hear in informal speech. But for other speakers, third-person singular "do/don't" is not a part of their dialect at any level of formality. Speakers of the second type only use third-person singular "do/don't" when they are consciously trying to create a particular effect. (The situation with "ain't" is similar.")

Comment: Because song lyrics are an artificial context, you can't tell whether the singer actually speaks a dialect of English where third-person singular "do/don't" is used, or whether the singer is using a grammatical construction from another dialect for some reason.

Comment: Asking for opinions is not considered on-topic on this website, because opinions cannot be referenced, or supported. It is one person's word against another's, and sometimes a dialogue can be fruitful and enlightening but, unfortunately, on the Internet more often than not, it ends up with one group insulting and name calling the other.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A A considered, fair and balanced response. IMHuO.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, English is not physics, or mathematics. It is very much a collection of opinions. That is how so-called "rules" of descriptive grammar are formed. See usage boards. The only aggressive type of answer is the one you posted.

Comment: No, I'm sorry if you took my comment as being aggressive, it was meant to be pragmatic. Tone is so difficult to convey in writing. But English is not based wholly on opinions, it is based on usage and primarily on speech, and the majority wins, always. So, while some grammarians may disagree and argue that one form is non-standard or evidence of bad grammar, the people, the speakers, will happily ignore them and carry on using English to fit their needs. Who cares what I may think if I read or hear someone say "She don't know nothing"?

Comment: My close vote was for POB (primarily opinion-based)